# Binding Android.Views.View with ViewModel with MvvmCross on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind the info contents window that apprears when clicking on a marker in a MapView for android.

I have created a custom manager class that takes an ItemSource and a MapView (ObservableCollection) and adds markers on the map as the collection changes.

Now I would like to bind the InfoContent window that is generated by [GetInfoContents(Marker marker)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#public-methods)

Currently I am forced to retrieve populate the fields manually as below but I would like the fields to be data bound directly in the layout with the current ViewModel

```
public override Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(object item, Marker marker)
        {
            var vm = item as DetailCalloutViewModel;
            if (vm != null) {
                var view = _layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_store_marker_info_window, null);
                var address = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address);
                var description = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.description);
                var badge = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.badge);

                address.Text = vm.Address;
                description.Text = vm.Location.Description;
                badge.Text = vm.BadgeNumber;
                return view;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you should try [BindingInflate](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/BindingContext/IMvxAndroidBindingContext.cs) from BindingContext:

```cs
var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.SomeLayout, null);
```

Update: For your problem, I'm not sure if this is not too hacky, but you could use `Mvx.RegisterSingleton(BindingContext);` in your MainActivity and then resolve this by `var bindingContext = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxBindingContext>();`.

---

Alternative: You could subscribe to your vm.PropertyChanged event and handle changes by yourself - actually writing your own BindingContext.

Comment: I have the manager that databinds the markers from the observable collection in a different class. The signature of the class is `public abstract class BaseMapViewDataBindingSource: Java.Lang.Object, IOnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
` and this. BindingInflate is not available from there

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. I updated a bit, but not very happy. Without BindingContext you can't use MvvmCross Binding.